# Lazy Evaluation in Spark. How does Spark load data from DB

Tags: apache-spark-sql

If suppose we have set limit of 100 , and Spark Application is connected to the DB with million records.Does Spark load all million record or loads 100 by 100 ?

Answer (score 0):

How does Spark load data from DB? It depends on the database type & its connector implementation. Of course for a distributed processing framework, a distributed data ingestion is always the primary aim for building connectors.

As a brief example, if we have a (1 Mil) records in a table, and we defined the number of partition to be 100 when we `load()`, then ideally the read task will be distributed to executors so that each executor reads a range of (10,000) records and store them in their corresponding partitions in memory. See [SQL Databases using JDBC.](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html)

> In the Spark UI, you can see that the numPartitions dictate the number of tasks that are launched. Each task is spread across the executors, which can increase the parallelism of the reads and writes through the JDBC interface

Spark provides flexible interfaces ([Spark DataSource V2](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/spark-datasource-v2-part-2/)) that allow us to build our own custom datasource connectors. The main design key here is parallelizing the read operation according to how many partitions defined. Also check ([figure 4](https://freecontent.manning.com/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-with-spark/)) to understand how distributed CSV ingestion works in Spark.

**Update**

**Read from JDBC connections across multiple workers**

```
df = spark.read.jdbc(
   url=jdbcUrl, 
   table="employees", 
   column="emp_no", 
   lowerBound=1, 
   upperBound=100000,
   numPartitions=100
) 
display(df)
```

In the above sample code, we used JDBC read to split the table read across executors on the `emp_no` column using the `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, and `numPartitionsparameters`.